# Quick Map Services (QMS) Google Satellite Imagery Source Date

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, remote-sensing, date, quickmapservices

I have digitized landform features using the QMS Google Satellite as a reference basemap in QGIS, and therefore need to know the date the image was taken. Is the plugin a 'live' updating feed from Google Earth, or a snapshot of when the basemap was created? How do I find this out?

Answer (score 1):

The QMS google satellite layer has this as its URL for getting tiles:

```
[tms]
url = https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}
```

so the datestamp will be whatever date Google used for those tiles.

Google Maps (web) satellite imagery seems to come from `khms[0-3].google.com` so might be different. Checking with timestamped imagery on the web or Google Earth is probably the definitive way of finding out.